# What happens first? .htaccess or php code?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If I use mod_rewrite to control all my 301 redirects, does this happen before my page is served? so if I also have a bunch of redirect rules in a php script that runs on my page, will the .htaccess kick in first?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When a request is made to the URI affected by the .htaccess file, then Apache will handle any rewrite rules before any of your PHP code executes.

Answer (score 43):

The .htaccess will kick in first.  If you look at the Apache request cycle:

[image: Apache Request Cycle]

PHP is a response handler.  mod_rewrite runs at URI translation, except for rewrite rules in .htaccess and <Directory> or <Location> blocks which run in the fixup phase.  This is because Apache doesn't know which directory it's in (and thus which <Directory> or .htaccess to read) until after URI translation.

In response to to gabriel1836's question about the image, I grabbed it from the second slide of [this presentation](http://stein.cshl.org/~lstein/talks/perl_conference/apache_api/) but it's originally from the book: [Writing Apache Modules in Perl and C](http://www.modperl.com/) which I highly recommend.

Comment: Could you post a link to image?

Comment: Interesting, I did not realize logging happened only after the response was delivered. +1 for finding that diagram.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the .htaccess file is parsed before your script is served.

Answer (score 4):

.htaccess happens first.

Answer (score 3):

htaccess is controlled by the webserver. This file will be taken in account before your PHP file.

For example, you could restrict access to a particular folder with your htaccess file. So, it have to be take in charge before your PHP.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The .htaccess is performed by Apache before the php script execution.
(imagine if the php script is executed and then the .htaccess make a redirection to another page...).

Answer (score 1):

You always can test this with the following command:

```
wget -S --spider http://yourdomain.com
```

With this command you see the who is responding to your request.

As all the others mentioned, .htaccess is first.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, the `.htaccess` more or less requires the relevant PHP code or files, as according to the rules specified in the `.htaccess`, meaning `.htaccess` is run first.